# TMS320 Floating Point (Texas Instruments DSP from '98)

Tags: c, dsp, algorithm, floating-point

**Background**

Is there anybody here who is an EE with programming experience who has worked with the Texas Instruments TMS320 C3X-series DSP? I am currently doing some work with the C3X for a project. My goal here is to convert C3X-formatted floating point ***hexadecimal*** values into IEEE 754 format. The code that I have works properly for:

[image]

Where x is the input *single* floating-point C3X hex number (represented as a UInt32).

The issue, is when I attempt to use a number such as *0.123*. It seems that I always get a *NaN* value as a result. I am currently using [this code snippet from the University of Florida](http://etd.fcla.edu/UF/UFE0005060/tmsieeeconv.c) that I have ported over to C#.

*Procedure*

1. Swap the sign and exponent fields to go from C3X to IEEE. I will not show this code (unless asked) as I believe it is very straightforward for anyone who has worked with this DSP.
2. Perform the University of Florida algorithm (linked above), that I believe I do not fully understand.
3. Combine the sign, exponent, and mantissa into single-precision IEEE 754 floating point.

*C# Implementation*

Here is the code used to implement the algorithm for when the C3X float-number happens to be between 0 and 1 (where the issue is happening). The `c30` object, represents the C3X floating point number. The `ieee` object represents the IEEE 754 floating point number.

EDIT: Upon popular request, here is a code sample that isn't awful. This sample is the properly working version where we dump in 15,913.35... (as C3X hexadecimal).

```
C30Float c30 = null;
UInt32 bias = 127;
Int32 mantissa = 0;
Int32 digit = 0;
double fraction = 0;
double exponent = 0;
double fpValue = 0;
double sign = 0;

// 1. Declare the new C3X floating point value.
c30 = new C30Float(0x0D78A56B);

// 2. Get the sign bit value.
sign = c30.GetSign();

// 3. Decide whether or not to do the flip.
if (sign == 1)
{
    // flip
    mantissa = c30.GetMantissa();
    mantissa = mantissa + 1;
    mantissa = (~mantissa) & 0x007FFFFF; // the first 9 bits have nothing to do with the mantissa
}
else
{
    mantissa = c30.GetMantissa();
}

// 4. Obtain part of the fraction (do the swim!).
for (int i = -1; i > -24; i--)
{
    // mantissa index
    int currentDigit = i + 23; // n = -23 + 23 => n = 0

    // shift forward (get the digit)
    digit = mantissa;
    digit = digit & (1 << currentDigit);

    // shift back (get the digit into the lowest place)
    digit = digit >> currentDigit;

    // apply the digit to the fraction
    fraction += digit * Math.Pow(2, i);
}

// 5. Obtain the exponential part of the number.
exponent = c30.GetExponent() + 0x7F;

// 6. Get the floating point number.
fpValue = Math.Pow(-1, sign);
fpValue *= (1 + fraction) * Math.Pow(2, exponent - bias);
```

I know that I *have not* provided the implementation details for the following:

```
GetMantissa()
GetExponent()
GetSign()
```

or...

```
SetMantissa()
SetExponent()
SetSign()
```

The reason for this is that all these are doing is entering/pulling the numbers to/from their respective fields as specified in [the TMS320 C3X User's Guide](http://www.ele.uva.es/~jesman/BigSeti/ftp/DSPs/Texas_Instrument_TMS320Cxx/TMS320C3x-J.pdf). Who knows, maybe that is where I'm going wrong, but for now I'd like to start at where I think the scope of the problem begins. If any of you believe that the issue is not here then feel free to ask about this implementation and I will provide more detail as warranted.

**Question**

My issue is apparently with numbers between 0 and 1. So if anyone has known C3X hex values and their known counter-part floats/reals that I can plug-and-chug that would be great so I can troubleshoot this algorithm.

Note: We don't have the DSP in front of us for what we're doing and can't just get the numbers out.

Comment: Are you remembering to convert the exponent between 8-bit signed (presumably 2's complement, I can't see it stated in the TI doc) and 8-bit unsigned with bias=127 (IEEE)? Last time I used the TMS320 it was still 16-bit integer only... (TMS32010)

Comment: @BrianDrummond that is called the "flip" and yes I am doing it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond have you worked with this DSP?

Comment: @BrianDrummond it seems like the numbers coming out of this thing that "should be" (and i'll say that because we're only here to discuss the DSP and NOT the nature of the application) small fractional numbers i.e. 0.234 seem to be having big Exponent values. Is this normal? Or impossible?

Comment: That is certainly where I would focus my intention. I think exponent(0.234) should be 124  (IEEE) or -3 =252 (TMS320).

Comment: I get the 252 part correctly. What do you get when you convert out C3X value (0.2381 which should be 0xFCEB4FCE)? I get -9.03... E +75... Seems too big?

Comment: @BrianDrummond It could be that my data is wrong (the 0.2831 equaling 0xFCEB4FCE value) and the algorithm could be correct. So let me know if you think the same thing.

Comment: Assuming 0xFCE..... is on the TMS side, why is the sign bit set? EDIT: it also looks as if the TMS format doesn't use a hidden bit for the mantissa? If so, you need to convert mant formats too.

Comment: That is what is throwing me also, sign bit should only be set for negatives... If what you're saying is, that that is an issue... I think that you might be confirming what I am thinking.

Comment: @BrianDrummond maybe answer this and elaborate on mantissa conversion?

Comment: Because I was wrong : the manual talks about an "implied most significant non-sign bit" (p.119) which is always the complement of the sign bit. So the big difference is that IEEE mantissae are always magnitude, TMS one is 2's comp. But yo do need to figure out what's flipping that sign bit. Without your code, I can't say.

Comment: @BrianDrummond this code sample is horrific, I will update with a better detailed/concise one. Don't give up on me yet!

Comment: @BrianDrummond updated.

Answer (score 1):

The [TMS320C3x User’s Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru031f/spru031f.pdf) lists a few test values:

- Hex value of C3X floating value interpreted as uint32 ~~
  Corresponding floating point value
- 0x02400000 ~~ +6.0   (see p. 5-10)
- 0x01C00000 ~~ -3.0   (see p. 5-11)
- 0xFB400000 ~~ (+3/64) (see p. 5-11)

I'm guessing you want code something more like:

```
/*
Convert from single-precision TMS C3x floating point
to single-precision IEEE floating point.
2016-07-11: minor tweaks by David Cary
2016-03-21: StevieV

(see
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223832/tms320-floating-point-texas-instruments-dsp-from-98
http://etd.fcla.edu/UF/UFE0005060/tmsieeeconv.c
http://etd.fcla.edu/UF/UFE0005060/tmsieeeconv.h
)
*/

C30Float c30 = null;
Int32 mantissa = 0;
double exponent = 0;
double sign = 0;
double fpValue = 0;

// 1. Declare the new single precision C3X floating point value.
c30 = new C30Float(0x0D78A56B);

/*
We could have followed page 5-21 in the TMS320C3x User's Guide
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru031f/spru031f.pdf
for C3X-->IEEE conversion.

But it seemed simpler to follow page 5-9
in the TMS320C3x User's Guide
"5.3.5 Determining the Decimal Equivalent of a TMS320C3x Floating-Point Format"
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru031f/spru031f.pdf
*/

// 2. Break up the C3X floating value into its components
// (Assume that these 3 functions deal with endianness).
sign = c30.GetSign(); // either 0 (positive) or 1 (negative)
exponent = c30.GetExponent(); // a signed 8-bit integer, -128 to +127.
mantissa = c30.GetMantissa(); // a 23-bit unsigned integer

// insert implied most significant bit to the left of MSB of the mantissa.
mantissa = ((1 + sign) << 23) + mantissa;

// 6. Get the floating point number.
// Move the binary point left 22 places,
// then adjust further based on exponent.
// (Possibly something like ldexp() or BitConverter.ToSingle()
// would be more efficient).
fpValue = (-sign) * mantissa * Math.Pow(2, exponent - 22);
return fpValue;
```

Comment: I see your answer, I just haven't gotten back to this project yet. I will take a look at this when I get back around to it.